# Self-compile Qt Webkit

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I have self-compiled Qt 5.4.1 and installed in /opt/qt-5.4.1.

However, I encountered an error while trying to 'qmake' my project file:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
```

I did `sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev` but the error persists.

I suspect then that apt-get install does not work when Qt-Core was self-compiled. The Qt Webkit source is available on https://qt.gitorious.org/qt
The question is, how and where should I install Webkit from source so that it can be detected while running qmake?

Comment: do your pro file have `QT += webkitwidgets`

Comment: Yes, I do have that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missed compilation of webkit while compilation of Qt. Read here how to resolve this issue:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/40378/solved-linux-unknown-module-s-in-qt-webkitwidgets

Answer (score 0):

might want to try:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

QtWebKit is not built anymore by default. You can build it after you have a proper build of Qt. Once you have your build of Qt clone the QtWebKit repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/qt/qtwebkit.git
```

then, make a new dir for the build files and from that directory enter the command:

```
/opt/qt-5.4.1/bin/qmake <path/to/qtwebkit>
make -j<n>
make install
```

Now you should be able to use QtWebKit with your build.